# gcc's extended initializer lists warning

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

`gcc` will warn about the following example code:

```
struct someStruct {
    char c;
    int i;
};

int main() {
    someStruct s { 'a', 3 };

    return 0;
}
```

> warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x

I want to make my code compatible to older compilers having no C++11 support.
Now when I try to compile it with either `-std=c++98` or even `-ansi -pedantic` it still issues the same warning and compiles.

Is this a compiler bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing an `=`:

```
someStruct s = { 'a', 3 };
```

Comment: Right, but thats an assignment and not an initialization. I just want to know why it compiles the given code even in C++98 mode.

Comment: @scai no, that's an initialization. It's copy initialization.

Comment: Ah you are right, thanks. I am still curious about the warning :).

Comment: @scai if you used stricter compilation flags (try `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c++98`) then this would be a compilation error, not a warning, because it is not C++98/C++03 standard compliant syntax without the `=` sign.

Comment: @juanchopanza `-pedantic-errors` is the flag I was looking for, thanks! Still seems weird that it compiles without this flag when specifying `-std=c++98`.

Comment: @scai - The standard explicitly allows compilers to accept code they understand the meaning of, once they have issued a diagnostic (warning). Just like "warning: missing semocolon", insert a semicolon, continue compilation.

Comment: @Bo Persson Thanks this explains gcc's behaviour.

Now, which answer do I accept? :)